# How to change an image based on another images visibility

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I've got a logo on a webpage which I would like to change depending on another images visibility.
The other image however is in a list of images which fade between each other and repeats.

What I'm trying to achieve is for Logo1 to appear when a specific image is shown, then switch back to Logo2 for all the other images

This is the code I currently have which doesn't work:

```
document.getElementById("featureImages").addEventListener("change", ChangeLogo3);
                    
function ChangeLogo3() {
    var x = document.getElementById("chosenBy");
        if (window.getComputedStyle(x).display === "none") {
            document.getElementById("homeLogo").src = img.src.replace("/images/defaultImages/Logo1.png", "/images/defaultImages/Logo2.png");
        }
}
```

'featureImages' is the ID of the Div which contains all the images to fade between.  None of them have an individual ID except for 'chosenBy' which is what an event listener should be listening for to become 'display: none'.

Each of the images however are coded as follows:

```
<div style="z-index: 17; position: absolute; display: none; opacity: 0.9999;">
<a target="_self" title="title" href="http://www.example.com">
<img class="image" height="450px" width="980px" alt="Alternative" src="/images/sliderImages/header1.jpg"/></a>
</div>
```

There's about 17 in total, all with different images.  There is also (I believe it's JS) some code to fade between each of them.

Comment: Create [mre] using <> button in editor to make a fiddle. So we can see everything that is going on.

Comment: The change event is fired for `<input>`, `<select>`, and `<textarea>` elements [ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) - You have to put your logic inside the one that cycles the images opacity.

Answer (score 0):

As Louys Patrice Bessette pointed in his comment, change event would not fire for your image wrap. You need to put your logic inside the part of code that handles image opacity. With jQuery you may check if element is hidden:

```
   const x = $('#chosen_by')
   if(x.is(':hidden')) {
     $('#homeLogo').attr('src', '/images/defaultImages/Logo2.png')
   }
```

You may also check absolute/relative urls in your code to make sure they are correctly pointing to the images you want to display. Also, I noticed in your JS code snippet that you are selecting elements by id but I don't see any id attributes in your html.

Comment: No `change` event fires for that image container `div`.

Comment: you are right, I had to keep that in mind. Thanks for pointing